# Android studio - how to get content URI in form "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%XYZ"

Tags: android

I am trying to get the URI of an image in local storage with the format "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:3951" but instead am getting this - "content://media/external/images/media/880". How do I get an image URI in the form of "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%XYZ" ????

Comment: "I am trying to get the URI of an image in local storage with the format" -- why? "but instead am getting this" -- what is wrong with that?

Comment: Please show how you try and get those uries.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have same problem. When I try to share file from this uri and choose intent, then instead of showing the actual file name it is showing the row number like 880 in this case. Below is code I used.

`intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
 intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"), FINISH_SHARING);
`

Comment: Is there any way of getting uri like this content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/Documents/New.pdf

Comment: @Coder: I do not know what "this uri" is. If you are referring to the example `Uri` in the question, then either the `MediaStore` has a bug (not supporting the `OpenableColumns` properly) or the app responding to `ACTION_SEND` has a bug (not using the `OpenableColumns` to get the display name, such as via `DocumentFile`). You could run a test in your app, using `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` for your name, then see what `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` returns.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have created a new question for the entire problem. Please see it and comment there for the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307286/intent-share-chooser-not-showing-correct-names